# Can I get the PHP response size inflight?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the number of bytes that have been sent back (or otherwise will be sent) to the client?

I will not use `ob_start()` because I cannot ensure that all output sent to the client can be guaranteed, even in the case of a fatal failure. Also, since it's an old complex web application I am not going to interfere with its output.

Comment: You could wrap your whole script in `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean`. Save the value of `ob_end_clean` and use `strlen` on it. Simply `echo` the saved value after you're done to send the actual response.

Comment: Might be something the webserver can do better than PHP...have a look at its logging capabilities. Unless you somehow want to use it in the code to do something more than just logging?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php

Comment: I've updated the question to qualify that ob_start is not an option.

Comment: For what purpose do you need this?  It matters, because there are lots of places to get this data, each with varying degrees of accuracy and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Theoretically a SAPI could count that, but in most cases this doesn't serve any purpose so it'S not done.